# Middleware - performance issues

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

I'm developing a Middleware for my client and it's found that there are some delay when executing the process.

We are currently investigating what's the exact causes of the issue, from architecture design to coding.

Below are part of the scripts we are calling, and just wondering if the codes itself is optimized and properly written?

There's **no error** from the codes below, just wondering if there's any **performance or coding issues**. Tks

```
public string getResponse(System.Type type, Object input, string taskName, string method)
{
    string response = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(type);
        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
        ser.WriteObject(mem, input);
        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray(), 0, (int)mem.Length);

        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            logger.Info("Sending [" + method + "] request to API[" + string.Format(Configuration.getTargetURI(), taskName) + "]");

            response = webClient.UploadString(string.Format(Configuration.getTargetURI(), taskName), method, data);

            logger.Info("Response of API[" + string.Format(Configuration.getTargetURI(), taskName) + "] successfully retrieved");
            logger.Debug("Response: " + response);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Info("Failed to invoke [" + method + "] request to API[" + string.Format(Configuration.getTargetURI(), taskName) + "], Error: " + ex.Message);
        logger.Error(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

        throw ex;
    }

    return response;
}

public string getResponseNoInput(string taskName, string method)
{
    string response = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(String.Format(Configuration.getTargetURI(), taskName));
        req.Method = method;
        req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        logger.Info("Sending [" + method + "] request to API[" + string.Format(Configuration.getTargetURI(), taskName) + "]");

        HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            response = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        logger.Info("Response of API[" + string.Format(Configuration.getTargetURI(), taskName) + "] successfully retrieved");
        logger.Debug("Response: " + response);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Info("Failed to invoke [" + method + "] request to API[" + string.Format(Configuration.getTargetURI(), taskName) + "], Error: " + ex.Message);
        logger.Error(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

        throw ex;
    }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: This might be better off on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd put the memory stream in a using.

Comment: hi Fred, i have posted another question to codereview section.

hi Mike, can you explain further? tks.